# How do CouchDB Filters work 'under the hood'?

Tags: couchdb

[*CouchDB: The Definitive Guide*](http://guide.couchdb.org/) is fantastic for understanding the inner workings of most of CouchDB's features and components. It goes into adequate detail on the use of views and does a great job of explaining how they're implemented within CouchDB. That being said, the guide does not contain any solid documentation on how _changes filtering actually *works*.

The [_changes section](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html) seems that it should contain that information but it is mysteriously absent.

How are CouchDB filters implemented 'under the hood'?

Comment: What *exactly* do you want to know? The *\_changes* section on [filters](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html#filters) describes how they work.

Comment: I want to know how they're implemented internally and better understand their efficiency. That section describes how to implement them in your application but does not touch on the structures and code behind filtering.

Comment: Well, you can checkout the source yourself since it is open source, however it might be a bit hard to grasp if you are not into Erlang. Take a look at [`couch_changes.erl`](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/src/couchdb/couch_changes.erl).

Comment: Guess it's an excuse to learn Erlang.